# Spark 1.6 - What is the difference between df.write.save() and df.write.parquet()

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

so I'm trying to learn some Spark 1.6 in Scala and I was wondering if there is any difference between save a dataframe like this

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip")
df.where($"mycol" === 0).write.save("/myfolder/")
```

As opposed to like this

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip")
df.where($"mycol" === 0).write.parquet("/myfolder/")
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: How was the dataframe 'df' created?. Did you read parquet file(s) or other formats?

Comment: I read another format. Is that relevant?